# Use Google fonts for printing

Tags: fonts, print-design, print-production, legal, google

Can I print the User Guide using Google fonts legally?

In particular, Roboto.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I have done so much commercial work using Roboto personally. And I have seen plenty of brading work which included the use of Roboto and various other Google font families.

No problem.